# Making an AJAX request go to the right URL

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I have this ajax request inside some jquery code for autocomplete:

```
$.ajax({type:"POST", url:("showable_videos/create.js"), data:{video:{profile:val}}});
```

The autocomplete acts on a field that is inside my video show view. Therefore, when it makes the AJAX request I get this error:

```
Started POST "/videos/showable_videos/create.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Apr 26 00:18:33 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/videos/showable_videos/create.js"):
```

Rails is prepending `/videos/` to the URL when I want it to just be `/showable_videos/create.js`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you didn't provide an absolute path (one rooted with "/") rails interprets that as "from the current path" instead of "from the root".

It's best to utilize rails path helpers instead of hard coding the urls like that.

Answer (score 2):

Put a leading slash on your url: `/howable_videos/create.js`. Without that, the browser treats it as relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Make it an absolute URL

```
 ... url:("/showable_videos/create.js") ...
```