# How do I make this AJAX request hit the right URL for its respective controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I have this AJAX request inside some jquery code that enables autocomplete:

```
$.ajax({type:"POST", url:("/showable_videos/create.js"), data:{video:{profile:val}}});
```

This field that has autocomplete is in the video show view. I get this error from the request:

```
Started PUT "/showable_video/create.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Apr 26 00:46:37 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/showable_videos/create.js"):
```

I'm trying to hit the create method in my showable_objects controller:

```
def create
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  @showable_video = current_user.showable_videos.create(:video => @video, :profile => @profile)
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html 
     format.js
  end
end
```

Please let me know if you'd like to see more code.

Comment: Does your routes file contain entry for `/showable_video/create.js`.

Comment: all I have is `resources :showable_videos`

Comment: by the way I meant `/showable_videos/create.js`

Comment: do not submit multiple versions of the same question. One question will suffice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an AJAX request go to the right URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785908/making-an-ajax-request-go-to-the-right-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create method is only accessible through post queries directly to the controller by default. So you should be accessing the url `/showable_videos.js` instead.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
$.ajax({type:"POST", url:("/showable_videos"), data:{video:{profile:val}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({type:"POST", url:("/showable_videos"), data:{video:{profile:val}}}); this will works