# AJAX request URL routing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

This strikes me as somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5785908/866022)

I've got an AJAX request on my page, and the page location is /a/b/c. I want to send the request to d. Sending it to /d or to a/b/d I can do. However, I need to route it to a/b/c/d. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the current page url and append `/d` to it.

eg.

```
var urlToUse = location.href + "/d";
```